# Uncaught ReferenceError: PhoneGap is not defined at file

Tags: android, cordova

this is my downloader.js file contents:

```
function Downloader() {}

Downloader.prototype.downloadFile = function(fileUrl,dirName,fileName,overwrite,win,fail) {

    //Make params hash optional.
    if (!fail) win = params;
    PhoneGap.exec(win, fail, "Downloader", "downloadFile", [fileUrl, params]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("downloader", new Downloader());
    PluginManager.addService("Downloader", "com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.Downloader");
});
```

I have  this integrated into android project.But when i run the project , I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: PhoneGap is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/downloader.js:10`. Can anyone tell what could be the problem.

Comment: have you included `phonegap.js` properly?? it should be defined above the `downloader.js` file

Comment: I have included cordova-1.8.1.js. I don't have phonegap.js file..Where could I get this

Comment: cordova.js also creates a variable `PhoneGap`, make sure cordova.js is included before the downloader.js file in your html file

Comment: i have put that in the answer so that you can accept the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the cordova.js file before the downloader.js file and it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloader.js"></script>
```

Comment: accept the answer (by clicking on green arrow on right) if it working

Comment: it's not solving the issue for me. and since js is asynchronous there's no way to guarantee that cordova.js will finish loading before downloader.js

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and and as Zoltan said, there's no guarantee in loading the cordova.js file in deviceready event. so I handled the onload event too(or with jquery `$(document).ready()`). make sure both events fired and then try to get the FileSystem.